# How to load Spatialite SQLite extension on macOS

Tags: macos, sqlite, spatialite

I am attempting to load the libspatialite extension in SQLite. As per the [installation guide](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/install-mac.html), I downloaded the latest [libspatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/binaries.html) and moved the included `libspatialite.1.1.3.dylib` file to `/usr/local/lib`.

```
greg /usr/local/lib $ls | grep libspatialite
libspatialite.1.1.3.dylib
```

However, I was unable to load the extension.

```
sql> SELECT load_extension('libspatialite.1.1.3.dylib')
[2017-09-19 10:45:25] [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (dlopen(libspatialite.1.1.3.dylib.dylib, 10): image not found)
```

I also tried storing `libspatialite.1.1.3.dylib.dylib` in the same directory as the sqlite file with no luck.

I have confirmed that `enable_load_extension` is `true` and I'm using DataGrip as my IDE. I have also quit DataGrip and rebooted to ensure any new binaries are collected. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this [homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/libspatialite.rb) for libspatialite:

> *New SQLite3 extension won't load via `SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite");` unless named `mod_spatialite.dylib` (should actually be mod_spatialite.bundle). See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/EqJAB8FYRdI*

So, if installing manually, you gonna need to rename the dynamic library file as per suggested. Or you can let Homebrew do the installation for you:

```
brew install libspatialite
```